# ip recognition is different

Tags: ip, datacenter

some months ago i bought a dedicated server from usa (http://www.dacentec.com/) datacenter.
my ips are look like this :  `162.248.243.blo blo blo`
when i check my ip in this site :  http://whatismyipaddress.com/
it shows me :

> ISP: Dacentec
>
> Services: None Detected
>
> Country: United States

why Services: None Detected and what did they do with this ip block?
also when i open some sites like google, yahoo, etc they show me india or china as country.
what is the problem about these ips and why i don't have a stable location for them?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the IP addresses. This is who they are registered to:

```
OrgName:        Dacentec, Inc.
OrgId:          DACEN-2
Address:        801 Main Steet NW
City:           Lenoir
StateProv:      NC
PostalCode:     28645
Country:        US
RegDate:        2010-01-21
Updated:        2012-10-03
Comment:        http://www.dacentec.com
Ref:            http://whois.arin.net/rest/org/DACEN-2
```

So why would the geolocation services say something different?

They rather want to know where they are being used than who they are registered to. They may be looking at what clients are seen from this IP range. They may have some access to information about, what sites those clients are accessing, what language settings they are using, which locale information they are looking up on various sites. And based on that try to deduce where those IP addresses are being used.

Since this IP range is used for a datacenter, you usually don't find many end users coming from that range of IPs. Any HTTP clients running in a datacenter tend to not be a browser, but rather just downloads of software.

But if there happen to be a proxy or a VPN service hosted in the same datacenter, then there could be some end users coming through that. And if lots of those are from Asia, that might be enough that the geolocation services have figured it out and marked that IP range as being used in Asia.

You shouldn't worry about it, it's not your server which has a problem it's the geolocation services.

As for the "Services" part, they have a link explaining it. As best I can tell, that feature of their site is simply not working.

Comment: really really thanks for your brilliant answer, i can not rank you. i was taliking one of my clients that uses my ip's as proxy. he told me are you using a satellite in india(dedicated ip - send & recieve). did you buy some ip's from us datacenter and using them through your satellite and this is why geolocation recognize you as india? you know what am i saying... is it possible some people are doing that and sell dedicated servers to us?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Dacentec has chopped up their Direct Allocation of IPs (162.248.240.0 - 162.248.247.255) pretty good, so they have "Reassigned" many, many small blocks all around the world. One would need an exact address to see where your tiny block is registered.